# Looping through object to find input name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of inputs like so:

```
<input name="education[1][yearbegin]" type="date" class="form-control">
<input name="education[2][yearbegin]" type="date" class="form-control">
```

The data is sent to my server to be verified, and if it's invalid it sends back data like so:

```
{
    "education.0.institution":["The education.0.institution field is required."],
    "education.0.degree":["The education.0.degree field is required."]
}
```

I don't always get more than 1 back, sometimes it could be many I am trying to loop over to append an error to the input like so:

```
var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
alertHtml += '<ul>';
$.each(errors, function (key, value) {
    $('.form-control[name=' + key + ']').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    alertHtml += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
});
alertHtml += "</ul>";
```

This doesn't work though, because it's trying to find the input name of:

```
education.1.yearbegin
```

Rather than

```
education[1]yearbegin
```

My inputs won't always be arrayed, but the ones that are don't append How can I append the error message to the input by changing the javascript? The json is being sent back by Laravel's array validation

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you have two issues here. 1: the name is incorrect ? 2: You need to append the errors correctly if it's an array?

Comment: That's correct, @JamesDale instead of it being [1] it's .1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unfortunate that the server accepts the names in one form but sends them back in another.

If we assume that dot syntax should always be converted to brackets syntax, it's fairly straightforward to update the keys:

```
var updated = key.split(".");
if (updated.length == 1) {
  updated = updated[0];
} else {
  updated = updated[0] + "[" + updated.slice(1).join("][") + "]";
}
```

For multi-part keys, that inserts `[` before the second and `][` in-between the second and third, third and fourth, etc.; and adds `]` at the end.

Example:

```js
var errors = [
  {"education.1.yearbegin":["The education.1.yearbegin field is required."]},
  {"education.2.yearbegin":["The education.2.yearbegin field is required."]}
];
errors.forEach(function(error) {
  Object.keys(error).forEach(function(key) {
    var updated = key.split(".");
    if (updated.length == 1) {
      updated = updated[0];
    } else {
      updated = updated[0] + "[" + updated.slice(1).join("][") + "]";
    }
    console.log("Original: " + key + ", updated: " + updated);
  });
});
```

If you're also struggling with showing all of the errors in the array next to the form control, you just loop through them. You're receiving an object where the property names in the object are the form control names, and the values are arrays of error messages. So we

1. Loop through the property names of that object, and for each property name:
2. Mark the relevant control, and
3. Loop through that entry's array of errors to append them to `alertHtml`.

Something long these lines:

```js
var errors = {
  "education.1.yearbegin":["The education.1.yearbegin field is required."],
  "education.2.yearbegin":["The education.2.yearbegin field is required."]
};
function fixKey(key) {
  var updated = key.split(".");
  if (updated.length == 1) {
    updated = updated[0];
  } else {
    updated = updated[0] + "[" + updated.slice(1).join("][") + "]";
  }
  return updated;
}
var alertHtml = '<ul>';
// #1: Loop through the object's property names
Object.keys(errors).forEach(function(key) {
  // #2: Mark the control, using the corrected name
  $('.form-control[name="' + fixKey(key) + '"]').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
  // #3: Loop through the errors
  errors[key].forEach(function(msg) {
    alertHtml += '<li>' + msg + '</li>';
  });
});
alertHtml += "</ul>";
$(document.body).append(alertHtml);
```

```css
.has-error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input name="education[1][yearbegin]" type="date" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input name="education[2][yearbegin]" type="date" class="form-control">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bcyexxpu/ I can't seem to get this to work, when I console log my errors, I get the following object, and an error: http://i.imgur.com/I8RpkX9.png

Comment: @randommman: You're using a single object as your starting point. The above uses an array, because you've clearly quoted in your question that you get back more than one of them. See my comment on the question, and the live example in the answer.

Comment: I apologize, I've updated my OP with the format I receive back,

Comment: @randommman: Then you just remove the outermost `$.each`. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue with the name:

I would just change the name to something that's a bit easier to read rather then having it like:

```
name="education[1][yearbegin]"
```

Maybe have it like:

```
name="EducationYearBegin1"
```

For the second issue:

You could check if the property is an array, so like this:

```
if (value instanceof Array) {
    value.forEach(function (item) {
        alertHtml += '<li>' + item + '</li>';
    })
} else {
    alertHtml += '<li>' + value + '</li>';

}
```

Maybe something like that?

The foreach would cover you if you ever had multiple errors in your array too.

Comment: with that suggestion, the inputs would no longer be arrays and cannot be accessed like an array server side.

Comment: Yeah use the below answer for that bit then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to convert `education.1.yearbegin` to be `education[1][yearbegin]`

See `fixName` function in this code.

```js
function fixName(name) {
  var newName =  name.replace(/\.\d\./, function ($1) {
    return "[" + $1.replace(/\./g, "") + "]"
  }).replace(/\].+/, function ($1) {
    return $1.replace(/\]/, "][") + "]"
  });

  return newName;
}

var errors = [{"education.1.yearbegin":["The education.1.yearbegin field is required."]},
{"education.2.yearbegin":["The education.2.yearbegin field is required."]}]; //$.parseJSON(data.responseText);
var alertHtml = document.querySelector("#alert");

alertHtml.innerHTML += '<ul>';
$.each(errors, function (key, obj) {
var realKey = fixName(Object.keys(obj)[0]);
    $('.form-control[name="'+ realKey +'"]').addClass('has-error');
    
    alertHtml.innerHTML += '<li>' + obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]][0]  + '</li>';
});
alertHtml.innerHTML += "</ul>";
```

```css
.has-error {
  color: red;
}

li {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="education[1][yearbegin]" type="date" class="form-control">
<input name="education[2][yearbegin]" type="date" class="form-control">

<div id="alert"></div>
```